# Function returns {} on the first run and then works correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a function which is ment to provide a content script some json data. The problem it works correctly only at 2nd+ run. Have no idea how to solve it :(

```
let links = {};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (request.get == "links") {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function (tabs_) {

            for (var i = 0; i < tabs_.length; i++) {
                if ((tabs_[i]['url'].match(some_var))) {
                    links[i] = [tabs_[i]['title'],
                        tabs_[i]['index']
                    ];
                }
            }
            console.log(links);              
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(links));
        sendResponse({reply: JSON.stringify(links)});
    }
});
```

The first time i run the function it returns an empty object {}, and then works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow` is asynchronous - so the  `sendResponse` is running before `function (tabs_)` get's a chance to do its thing ... put the last two lines INSIDE the callback - like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.get == "links") {
        chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function (tabs_) {
            const links = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs_.length; i++) {
                if ((tabs_[i]['url'].match(some_var))) {
                    links[i] = [tabs_[i]['title'],
                        tabs_[i]['index']
                    ];
                }
            }
            console.log(links);              
            console.log(JSON.stringify(links));
            sendResponse({reply: JSON.stringify(links)});
        });
        return true; // this signifies the response is asynchronous
    }
});
```

Comment: It solved the issue on the background.js side, but now i've got another one on the content scrip'st: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

Comment: Oh, wait ... let me read the documentation for getAllInWindow - which has been Deprecated since Chrome 33

Comment: no, wait, it's to do with `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` - there's some mechanism you can use to tell it you're using an asynchronous response